# How do I draw the following symbols

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I am trying to represent the calculus of relations, from Tarski's paper. How do I represent the following [image: following] ?
SideNote:
I did go through http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/files/symbols-all.pdf
and https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf
and anyother document I could find.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only challenging one is the fourth in the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\langle \cdot,\bullet^{-},\cup,\mathbin{{\bullet}{\breve{\phantom{\imath}}}},1\rangle
\]

\end{document}
```

Of course you want to make a new command for it.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I agree. May I know how you figured it out, other than years of practice and familiarity? Any references would be welcome.

Comment: @GermanShepherd `texdoc comprehensive` from a terminl or http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf For the complicated one, practice in solving similar problems.

Comment: Please, could you explain why did you use `\mathbin`?

Comment: @Sigur From the standard usages, I guess it is an operation symbol.

Comment: Ah, ok. I supposed it could be to get some appropriate positioning. So, the same for the 2nd one?!

Comment: On a totally irrelevant (to tex) note, how does one pronounce the 4th symbol?( It denotes the relational converse)

Comment: @GermanShepherd I guess David Carlisle would call it `zzz`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but this website has been very helpful. It allows you to draw a symbol and it does a reverse search of Latex commands.

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html